# How to add missing data entries in an array between a given start date and end date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array named `plot_data`. In that I have two object properties date `x` and value `y`. The dates are actually past dates. In that array a few dates are missing somewhere at multiple places. So, whatever dates are missed I want to add them in the array.

plot_data array is like this

```
0: {x: Fri Apr 06 2018 22:30:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), y: 93.9}
1: {x: Sat Apr 07 2018 09:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), y: 69.3}
2: {x: Tue Apr 10 2018 10:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), y: 71.2}
3: {x: Wed Apr 11 2018 11:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), y: 67.2}
4: {x: Sat Apr 14 2018 10:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), y: 71.2}
5: {x: Sun Apr 15 2018 11:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), y: 67.2}
```

I want the output of the array like this.

```
0: {x: Fri Apr 06 2018 22:30:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), y: 93.9}
1: {x: Sat Apr 07 2018 09:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), y: 69.3}
2: {x: Sun Apr 08 2018 09:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), y: null}
3: {x: Mon Apr 09 2018 09:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), y: null}
4: {x: Tue Jun 10 2018 10:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), y: 71.2}
5: {x: Wed Jun 11 2018 11:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), y: 67.2}
6: {x: Thu Jun 12 2018 10:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), y: null}
7: {x: Fri Jun 13 2018 11:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), y: null}
8: {x: Sat Jun 14 2018 10:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), y: 71.2}
9: {x: Sun Jun 15 2018 11:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), y: 67.2}
```

I am not getting idea how to do this, since we have to consider number of dates in a month. Please help.

Comment: The data entries shown in your example `plot_data` array are recorded at different time of the day. How to decide whether or not an entry is missing.  Do you simply expect on record per day? Please revise your question. It will also be great if you revise you examples to have proper Javascript code.

Comment: Yes, I am expecting a record per day, we can hard code times to any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the next date by just adding the 24 hours then you will not have to care about the date in the month.

I have removed the timezone, you can set the same as per your requirement.

```js
let arr = [{x: 'Fri Apr 06 2018 22:30:00', y: 93.9},
{x: 'Sat Apr 07 2018 09:00:00', y: 69.3},
{x: 'Tue Apr 10 2018 10:00:00', y: 71.2},
{x: 'Wed Apr 11 2018 11:00:00', y: 67.2},
{x: 'Sat Apr 14 2018 10:00:00', y: 71.2},
{x: 'Sun Apr 15 2018 11:00:00', y: 67.2}]

let i=0;
while(i < arr.length-1) {
 let nextday = new Date(new Date(arr[i].x).getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
 if(nextday.getDay() != (new Date(arr[i+1].x)).getDay()) {
  arr.splice(i+1, 0,  {x: nextday.toString(), y: null});
 };
        i++
}

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to take the first element into account.